# R: Read multiple files from zip without extracting

Tags: r, csv, io, zip, bigdata

For a given dataset, I have around 5 - 20 zip files, each containing potentially hundreds of CSVs. I would like to be able to use fread to read in all the CSVs without extracting them from the zip files. I am currently able to download the zip files, extract them and then process the CSVs, however this takes a large amount of disk space and RAM.

Here is some example data (just grabbed this from another SO question):

```
write.csv(data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 1:2), tf1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
write.csv(data.frame(x = 2:3, y = 2:3), tf2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
write.csv(data.frame(x = 3:4, y = 3:4), tf3 <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
zip(zipfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip"), files = c(tf1, tf2))
zip(zipfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip"), files = c(tf1, tf3))
zip(zipfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip"), files = c(tf2, tf3))
```

Existing method:

```
for (i in dir(pattern="\\.zip$"))
    unzip(i)
lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.csv"), fread)
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
library(rio)
lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.zip"), import, fread = TRUE)
```

Which gives this output:

```
[[1]]
  V1 x y
1  1 2 2
2  2 3 3

[[2]]
  V1 x y
1  1 1 1
2  2 2 2

[[3]]
  V1 x y
1  1 1 1
2  2 2 2

Warning messages:
1: In parse_zip(file) :
  Zip archive contains multiple files. Attempting first file.
2: In parse_zip(file) :
  Zip archive contains multiple files. Attempting first file.
3: In parse_zip(file) :
  Zip archive contains multiple files. Attempting first file.
```

It appears that only the first CSV is read in each zip file. I've have searched quite a bit, but haven't yet found the solution to this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract one csv at a time?

Comment: No, the CSVs are being read in without extracting them at all.

Comment: I wouldnt think that you  can  read the csv's in without extracting them?

Comment: I know that there are not any CSV files produced (at least that I can find). It could be that the CSV files are loaded into memory in the same way as if you had extracted them and then used fread, but I am not sure about that. At a minimum, this method should clean up some disk space even if it doesn't alleviate the memory issue.

Comment: The files need to be extracted before reading. rio::import just hides this. To see look at `import` which leads to `rio:::parse_zip`

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it unzips them to a temp directory and then deletes it when done. That still works for me, just need to figure out how to get it to read all the CSVs instead of just the first one.

Comment: Get a list of the csv files with `lst <- unzip(file, list = TRUE)` (this doesnt extract them) and then loop through them to extract them with `unzip(file, files = lst[i])`

Comment: The whole point is that I do not want to explicitly extract all the files and then clean them up. I have updated the question showing how I currently do it.

Comment: okay.. i'll step away as i dont understand. To use any csv stored in a zip folder, you will need to extract it.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
#First obtain contents of your archive:   

 list_of_txts<-unzip("your.zip",list=TRUE)[,1]
 list_of_txts<-list_of_txts[str_detect(list_of_txts,".xml")] # use ".csv" since you are looking for csv files instead 


#Then loop over it without unzipping:

final_data<-list("vector")
for (i in 1:length(list_of_txts)){
  conn<-unz("your.zip", list_of_txts[i])
  final_data[[i]]<-fread(conn) #replace fread with the command you want to use to read in the data. Worked with readr::read_csv()
}
```

Comment: I know this was from a while ago, but I am getting the following error when trying to apply this method: `Error in fread(conn, nrows = 10) : 
  input= must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or, the input data itself containing at least one \n or \r` any idea what the issue would be?